# Is there a loop for calculating the product value of items?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code that'll calculate the better value of different product sizes. Is there a loop so that I can calculate the better value of an infinite amount of product sizes?

For example, when the code asks the user how many products there are, and the user inputs 59, it will ask for the cost and the mass for each of those individual products.

Here's my code (I excluded the rest of my code because there was no point including it here):

```
#This part greets the user, and lets the user know that the application has started
print("Hello there!")
#This starts off the loop, but this variable may be changed later on
cont = "yes"
#This is the actual loop
while cont == "yes" or cont == "Yes" or cont == "YES":
  print("Choose an option below:")
#This shows the options
  print("1) Calculate the value of different product sizes")
  print("2) Calculate the sale price")
  print("3) Calculate the discount")
  print("4) Create a shopping list")
  print("5) Exit")
#This part lets the user choose what they would like to do
  option = float(input("Choose an option (1/2/3/4/5): "))
#This is what happens if the user chooses Option 1
#This is the part that calculates the value of up to 10 products
  if option == 1:
#This notifies the user that there can only be up to 10 product sizes entered
    print("Please note: This code can only take up to 10 product sizes.")
#This asks the user how many products there are
    products = int(input("How many products are there? "))
#This is just in case the user still types that there are over 10 products
    if products > 10:
      print("This code can only take up to 10 product sizes.")
      print("Please enter only up to 10 product sizes below.")
    if products <= 1:
#This tells the user that they must enter at least 2 product sizes to compare them
      print("You must enter at least two product sizes to compare.")
    if products >= 1:
#This asks for information because the user may just be looking for the $/g.
      cost1 = float(input("Cost of first product($): "))
      mass1 = float(input("Mass of first product(g): "))
      ans1 = cost1/mass1
      a = ans1
#This part substitutes undefined variables with a blank
#This is in case the number of sizes being compared doesn't reach 2 to 10
      ans2 = ""
      ans3 = ""
      ans4 = ""
      ans5 = ""
      ans6 = ""
      ans7 = ""
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are two or more product sizes
    if products >= 2:
      cost2 = float(input("Cost of second product($): "))
      mass2 = float(input("Mass of second product(g): "))
      ans2 = cost2/mass2
      if a > ans2:
        a = ans2
#This is for when there are three or more product sizes
    if products >= 3:
      cost3 = float(input("Cost of third product($): "))
      mass3 = float(input("Mass of third product(g): "))
      ans3 = cost3/mass3
      if a > ans3:
        a = ans3
      ans4 = ""
      ans5 = ""
      ans6 = ""
      ans7 = ""
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are four or more product sizes
    if products >= 4:
      cost4 = float(input("Cost of fourth product($): "))
      mass4 = float(input("Mass of fourth product(g): "))
      ans4 = cost4/mass4
      if a > ans4:
        a = ans4
      ans5 = ""
      ans6 = ""
      ans7 = ""
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are five or more product sizes
    if products >= 5:
      cost5 = float(input("Cost of fifth product($): "))
      mass5 = float(input("Mass of fifth product(g): "))
      ans5 = cost5/mass5
      if a > ans5:
        a = ans5
      ans6 = ""
      ans7 = ""
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are six or more product sizes
    if products >= 6:
      cost6 = float(input("Cost of sixth product($): "))
      mass6 = float(input("Mass of sixth product(g): "))
      ans6 = cost6/mass6
      if a > ans6:
        a = ans6
      ans7 = ""
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are seven or more product sizes
    if products >= 7:
      cost7 = float(input("Cost of seventh product($): "))
      mass7 = float(input("Mass of seventh product(g): "))
      ans7 = cost7/mass7
      if a > ans7:
        a = ans7
      ans8 = ""
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are eight or more product sizes
    if products >= 8:
      cost8 = float(input("Cost of eighth product($): "))
      mass8 = float(input("Mass of eighth product(g): "))
      ans8 = cost8/mass8
      if a > ans8:
        a = ans8
      ans9 = ""
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are nine or more product sizes
    if products >= 9:
      cost9 = float(input("Cost of ninth product($): "))
      mass9 = float(input("Mass of ninth product(g): "))
      ans9 = cost9/mass9
      if a > ans9:
        a = ans9
      ans10 = ""
#This is for when there are ten or more product sizes
    if products >= 10:
      cost10 = float(input("Cost of tenth product($): "))
      mass10 = float(input("Mass of tenth product(g): "))
      ans10 = cost10/mass10
      if a > ans10:
        a = ans10
#There's nothing for 10+ sizes for there is no loop for it'll make the code too long
#This tells the user the which product size(s) is/are the ones with the best value
#This tells the user the final result
    if products >= 1:
      print("The product(s) with the best value is/are these product number(s):")
      if ans1 == a:
        print(1)
      if ans2 == a:
        print(2)
      if ans3 == a:
        print(3)
      if ans4 == a:
        print(4)
      if ans5 == a:
        print(5)
      if ans6 == a:
        print(6)
      if ans7 == a:
        print(7)
      if ans8 == a:
        print(8)
      if ans9 == a:
        print(9)
      if ans10 == a:
        print(10)
#This tells the user the cost per gram of the product(s) with the best value is/are
      print("The cost per gram is $", a, "/ g")
#This tells the user to pick the size with best quality if multiple are above
#Sometimes, items with the best value may not have the best quality.
      print("If multiple items are above, consider the one with best quality.")
```

I'm just a beginner at coding, and at using Stack Overflow. Please don't mind mistakes I make and if I need to elaborate on anything, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use lists. Definitely.

Comment: How can I use a list? And can you explain how?

Comment: `newlist = []` and you append an item to the list with `newlist.append(item)`  You can iterate an infinite or dynamic list with `for item in newlist:`  item is what is being iterated on.

Comment: This is a much too broad question, SO is not supposed to replace tutorials. But this is a basic part of any good tutorial/book you'll find.